# Assigning integers to a list of items?

Tags: algorithms

I have an ordered list of items. Some items already have integer weights. It is desirable that the difference between two adjacent items is as uniform as possible. What would be a good algorithm to assign weights?

Edit: we have a $S \subset {1..n}$ so that $\forall k \in S$ $w_k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  We are looking for $w_i|i>=1 \land i<=n \land i \notin S$ so that $\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n}(w_i-w_{i-1})^2$ is minimal.

Comment: Linear interpolation between the given weights, rounded to the nearest integer, is not so bad. It all depends on what you mean by "as uniform as possible".

Comment: I hope that's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear interpolation is the best you can do: if between two successive elements $s,t$ of $S$ there is a distance of$~d=t-s$, and $\Delta=w_t-w_s$, then the $d-1$ intermediate values should be chosen so as to divide $\Delta$ into parts of at most two sizes, differing by$~1$. To be precise into $d-(\Delta\bmod d)$ parts of size $\lfloor\Delta/d\rfloor$ and the remaining $\Delta\bmod d$ (which could be$~0$) parts of size $\lceil\Delta/d\rceil$.

That one cannot do better follows from the simple observation that for fixed $x,z$ and variable $y$ one minimises $(y-x)^2+(z-y)^2$ by taking $y=\frac{x+z}2$ (and in general one minimises the sum-of-squared-distances to any given finite set of points by taking their barycentre). This means that in an optimal solution each variable $w_i$ must be as close to $\frac{w_{i-1}+w_{i+1}}2$ as possible, which is at that value if it is integer, and otherwise at distance $\frac12$ from it. This means successive differences can differ by at most$~1$. Moreover, in the latter case the "excess unit" can be moved across $w_i$ by changing it to the other candidate, and it easily follows that with between $w_s$ and $w_t$ no more than two differences can occur, necessarily $\lfloor\Delta/d\rfloor$ and $\lceil\Delta/d\rceil$.

Comment: What would you do with $i<min(S)$ (and $j>max(S)$ of course) ?

Comment: Well, if a value is fixed only on one side of the interval, I guess linear interpolation (more properly extrapolation) would be just repeating that value across the remaining interval, making differences $0$ there. In any case, this clearly is the optimal solution.